# RAML: Referencing uriParameters in resources

Tags: api, mime-types, raml

I'm writing an API spec in RAML, and was wondering if it was possible to reference uri parameters in order to create dynamic mime types. Something along the lines of

```
baseUri: http://api.mycompany.com/{version}

/first_resource:
  get:
    responses:
      200:
        body:
          application/custom.mime.type.{version}+json
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently (v 0.8) such a behaviour is not part of the [spec](http://raml.org/spec.html).

What you are after in your example code may add a path of error for developers - that your server implementation will have to cater for: What happens if a request for a resource some where at `http://api.mycompany.com/v1` is made, but for some reasons contains a `Content-Type: custom.mime.type.v2+json`-Header?

When going with custom versioned MIME types, my suggestion is to have a non-versioned URL to avoid such a situation by design. For clients unable to send the required headers you may still offer a fallback using the query string or what-have-you...